# Representing numbers as sum of distinct odd numbers

Tags: combinatorics

> For each positive integer $n$, let $W(n)$ denote the number of ways to write $n$ as a sum of the numbers $1,3,5,7,\ldots$, using each number at most once. Prove that $W(n)\leq W(n+1)$ for all $n\geq 2$.

Examining the first few values: $W(1)=1,W(2)=0,W(3)=W(4)=W(5)=W(6)=W(7)=1$, $W(8)=W(9)=2$. For any representation of $n$ that does not contain $1$, we can get a representation of $n+1$ by adding $1$. This means we're left to compare representations of $n$ containing $1$ and representations of $n+1$ *not* containing $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider combining terms. Try first before looking below!

> If the representation includes a $1$, removing it and increasing the largest term by $2$ increases the sum by $1$. Remember to prove that the resulting representations are all different.